# Android - Click on ActionBar app icon, create new activity instance

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have an ActionBar in my Android app (API Level 14).
There is a home button with my app icon. In MainActivity I write a short Text in an EditText View.
When I navigate to PreferenceActivity the icon gets an arrow to signal me, I can navigate to home Activity (MainActivity).

```
  // PreferenceActivity-onCreate
  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
  actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

I click on that app icon in ActionBar to return to MainActivity

```
// PreferenceActivity
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{
   switch (item.getItemId()) 
   {
     case android.R.id.home:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
     default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
}
```

Now my MainActivity was created again und the text in EditText is gone.
I thought I can keep alive the MainActivity with die Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP.
I want to have a behaviour like i use my return button on device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to return to an existing instance of `MainActivity`, you need to do this:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Using CLEAR_TOP alone causes a new instance of `MainActivity` to be created.

Comment: This way doesn't work. But when I write 2 addFlags it works fine.   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

Comment: Ah...so sorry, you need a single "|" and not "||" between the 2 flags. My fault. You want a **bitwise** OR, not a **logical** OR. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Right, I have to noticed that

Comment: I have loaded the webview inside the action bar tabs. I am starting the intent for button click inside the tab. I have specified the above two flags for my intent. But the webview is always recreated. I have specified android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" for my activity. But still the activity webview is always recreated. How can I fix this issue? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the correct way of doing this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15933890/238768

Using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP will cause the exact opposite behaviour of what Gepro wants to do!