# DisplayMessageActivity back button keeps crashing my android application

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

The default back button that appears next to the icon in the action bar crashes when i try to return to `MainActivity`. `MainActivity` calls `DisplayMessageActivity` from there I click the default back button and the app crashes.

Logs show message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(24509): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity DisplayMessageActivity does not have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY <meta-data>  element in your manifest?)
```

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="net.assemblyx.playzone"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="net.assemblyx.playzone.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="net.assemblyx.playzone.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="net.assemblyx.playZone.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="net.assemblyx.playZone.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Try and remove the meta-data tag. Follow this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15535313/return-to-parent-activity-with-a-parent-activity-error-in-the-manifest

Comment: WOW!!! it was a typo, i had playZone and should have been playzone, the follow this link last comment brought it to my attention, thanks so much

Comment: user3368761, please post an answer and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: as im sure you already know, have to wait two days to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

package name had playZone and should have been playzone