# Back button calls onDestroy() on parent

Tags: android

Why does the back tubbon call onDestroy() on the parent?

I have the following scenario:

1. Activity A that opens Activity B via an intent

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(parent.getContext(), activityB.class);
   intent.putExtra(STATE_REST, gson.toJson(myObject));
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. When I click on back on activity B (and only then) activity A fires onDestroy() followed by onCreate().

**Manifest:**

*Activity A*

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

*Activity B*

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MenuActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/menu_title"
    android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity">
</activity>
```

Comment: add manifest declaration please.

Comment: Manifest is ok. Now add `onBackPressed` implementation and `onCreate` methods of both `Activities`.

Comment: And the question. Did you call `setResult`? If - YES - where you do that?

Comment: I want to use the default behavior so I don't overwrite onBackPressed and I don't call setResult and `onCreate()` should not play a role here because after the back button is pressed it should fire `onStart()` (in activity A) not not onCreate() (neither should it call `onDestroy()`) am I missing something?

Comment: Actually this is related on situation. Look on activity lifecycle. If You press back button backStack acitivity should be going to onResume state. BUT. If Other application need the memory - activity get behavior like from start application.

Comment: Yes I know that but this not where the issue is coming from. onDEstroy() gets call systematically after back is pressed the problem is not a random memory allocation issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem seems to be resolved in the flowing [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819019/why-is-ondestroy-always-called-when-returning-to-parent-activity):
**Why is onDestroy always called when returning to parent activity?**

Good luck.