# Up Button Calls OnDestroy of Parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

Right off the top, I want to clarify something: The button that I am struggling with is NOT the `back` button. I am referring to the `up/home` button in the ActionBar / Toolbar at the top of the app, not the Android button at the bottom. There are a few [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819019/why-is-ondestroy-always-called-when-returning-to-parent-activity) of a similar nature, but they address the back button, not the up button.

Here is the situation: I have an Activity A that has a ListView fragment. When the user clicks on a list view item, it launches Activity B. Pretty typical. Activity A has an `EditText` field in the toolbar that allows the user to enter a search parameter. If the user hits the `up/home` button from Activity B, I return successfully to Activity A. However, I want Activity A to show the same text in the `EditText` field that was there when they left it. If the user hits the `back` button, this text is restored. But if they navigate with the `up/home` button, the `EditText` field is empty.

Using some log statements, I can see that when a list item is tapped from activity A, `onSaveInstanceState` and `onStop` are both called (but `onDestroy` is NOT called at that point.) From activity B, when the `up/home` button is tapped, `onDestroy` from activity A is *immediately* called, followed by `onCreate`, etc. However, the bundle `savedInstanceState` is null, presumably since `onDestroy` was just called.

Why is `onDestroy` called when returning to Activity A? This makes no sense to me. Here is what I have in the manifest:

```
<activity
  android:name=".Activity.ActivityA"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:parentActivityName=".Activity.ParentActivity"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  android:launchMode="singleTop"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />

<activity
  android:name=".Activity.ActivityB"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:parentActivityName=".Activity.ActivityA"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

Here are the relevant methods in Activity A:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null)
            initializeActionBar();

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Log.d(TAG, "on create");

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "saved instance state not null");
            if (savedInstanceState.getString("search_text") != null)
                etSearch.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("search_text"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("search_text", etSearch.getText().toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "on Save instance state");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, "on restore instance state");

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState.getString("search_text") != null)
              etSearch.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("search_text"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "on resume");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "on stop");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "on destroy");
    }

private void initializeActionBar() {

    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_with_edittext);

    etSearch = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.actionbar_searchfield);
    etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            if(event != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                initiateNewSearch();
                etSearch.clearFocus();

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(etSearch, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    etSearch.requestFocus();
}
```

I don't think that any of the code in Activity B is relevant here.

This is my console output when a user taps on a listview item in Activity A:

> on Save instance state
> on stop

And then this is what is generated when the user taps on the `up/home` button from activity B:

> on destroy 
> on create 
> on resume

If there is anything else that may be of help, please let me know. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Hi Alex, could you please include the code for your `onOptionsItemSelected`. I am wondering if you should not try and handle the "up navigation" (`android.R.id.home`) using something like `NavUtils`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why default up button implementation creates a new activity but a working solution for me is to override `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id== android.R.id.home ){
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Also this solution works for me:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too, and after a little more digging found the correct solution is to make a change in the manifest to add the following to your parent activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Details are explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276027/how-can-i-return-to-a-parent-activity-correctly/15933890#15933890).