# Implement Up Navigation

Tags: android, android-intent, up-navigation

I'm trying to implement a good Up navigation on my Android app.

For instance I want to go from `DetailsActivity` to `MasterActivity`. To do so I use the following code:

```
final Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MasterActivity.class);
upIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
supportNavigateUpTo(upIntent);
```

It works great if `MasterActivity` is already open in the background: it closes the current activity (and all the activities in the stack over `MasterActivity`) and fires the method `onNewIntent` on `MasterActivity`.

But, if `MasterActivity` is not in the stack, the method simply closes `DetailsActivity` and nothing else happens.

What I would like to achieve is that, if `MasterActivity` is not in the stack, the current aActivity gets closed and a new instance of `MasterActivity` gets created.

I already tried, with no success, the following flags combination:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Have you any idea on how to solve my issue?

Thanks a lot for your time

**EDIT**

The parent Activity need to be specified at runtime. In fact, the parent Activity can be `ActivityA`,`ActivityB` or `ActivityC`.

Let me better explain the problem. My app manage TV Shows. I have a `MainActivty`, a `TVShowActivity`, a `SeasonActivity` and a `EpisodeActivity`.

In the navigation drawer from every Activity I want to be able to jump to the parent Activity:

-On `EpisodeActivity` I want to go to `SeasonActivity`, `TVShowActivity` or `MainActivity`;

-On `SeasonActivity` I want to go `TVShowActivity` or `MainActivity`;

-On `TVShowActivity` I want to go to `MainActivity`.

My app currently works if my Activity stack is something like: `MainActivty` => `TVShowActivity` => `SeasonActivity` => `EpisodeActivity`.

The problem is that sometimes the user can reach `EpisodeActivity` directly from `MainActivity`, and I want to be able to use the same navigation pattern.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12276100/3322203 

I think you need a look at that solution.
perfect example.

Comment: Please see my edits: I need to specify the parent Activity at runtime

Comment: Use Fragments, so you can stick to single Activity

Comment: you should use `supportShouldUpRecreateTask` as the doc says 

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#supportNavigateUpTo(android.content.Intent)

Comment: I cannot completely change my app just to implement that. Beside that, my app is really complex and such a modification would require an incredible amount of time

Comment: @Mohammad supportShouldUpRecreateTask  returns false no matter what in my tests

Answer (score -1):

On each activity you can keep for example two buttons providing an onclick event in the properties of their xml and provide intent code in java class:

`    public void youronclickname(View v)
    {
    Intent myintent = new Intent(your sourceclass, to destination class);
    startActivity(myintent);
    }    '

similarly try this with your next class

Comment: Please read the question! My question asks how to correctly create the Intent, not how to handle the click