# Issues re-starting a finish()ed android activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, crash

I have two android activities with one single button on both.

The activity `DetailsActivity` is my `MAIN` activity.

```
public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_activity_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
    }



    public void gotoSubDetails(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SubDetailsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

And my `SubDetailsActivity` is as follows:

```
public class SubDetailsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.sub_details_activity_layout);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
    }



    public void gotoDetails(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class); 
        startActivity(intent); // Restarting the finish()ed activity here.
        finish();
    }
}
```

And this is how I mentioned my button in `details_activity_layout.xml` for `DetailsActivity.java`:

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/details_submit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/to_sub_details"
        android:onClick="gotoSubDetails" />
```

And this is how I have mentioned my button in `sub_details_activity_layout.xml` for `SubDetailsActivity.java`:

```
    <Button android:id="@+id/sub_details_submit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/back_to_details"
        android:onClick="gotoDetails" />
```

These are my both activities in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <activity android:name="DetailsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="SubDetailsActivity">
    </activity>
```

When I click the `button` in `DetailsActivity`, the activity `finish()`es properly and `SubDetailsActivity` starts up.

But when I click the `button` in `SubDetailsActivity` to get back to the `finish()`ed `DetailsActivity`, the app straight away crashes on my LG L90 phone.

Where am I going wrong? Any help? Please.

**PS:**
I cannot post the log cat report as I did not test it on my mac but directly on my phone. I don't have an emulator. I am compiling the code on my terminal and transferring the `.apk` file on my phone via bluetooth.

**EDIT:**
Ok guys. Now this is really funny!

I removed the

```
android:onClick="gotoSubDetails"
```

and

```
android:onClick="gotoDetails"
```

from my `details_activity_layout.xml` and `sub_details_activity_layout.xml` respectively. And I loaded the `android.widget.Button`'s in my `DetailsActivity.java` and `SubDetailsActivity.java` and added an `android.view.View.OnClickListener` on both of them and overrode the `onClick(View)` method.

This is what I did in my `DetailsActivity.java`:

```
public class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_activity_layout);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.details_submit);
        button.setOnClickListener(new DetailsSubmitListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
    }


    public class DetailsSubmitListener implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SubDetailsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what I did in my `SubDetailsActivity.java` class:

```
public class SubDetailsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_activity_layout);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sub_details_submit);
        button.setOnClickListener(new SubDetailsSubmitListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
    }


    public class SubDetailsSubmitListener implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

And this **miraculously** worked fine.

So what was the problem with the `.xml` attributes in my layout files? And how different is it from the hardcoded listener in my `.java` file? This thing has confused me. `finish()`ed activities can be re-started. Thats what I discovered with my change in the program. Please shed some light of knowledge on this.

Comment: Post the logcat from the crash

Comment: The code you posted is confusing. You state "And my SubDetailsActivity is as follows:", yet the code that follows is "class DetailsActivity..."

Comment: It's still impossible to say without the logcat output of the crash. What you have posted *seems* fine

Comment: @codeMagic I did not test it on my mac. As I don't have an emulator installed. So I need to transfer the `.apk` to my phone via bluetooth. I cannot post the log cat output due to this reason.

Comment: Can you please tell me if this is the proper way to re-start a `finish()`ed activity? If no, then what m I supposed to do?

Comment: As I said, it looks fine from what I can see. Install genymotion and/or use Crashlytics, bugsense, or some other logging software. You need to see the stacktrace to see what is causing the crash

Answer (score 2):

Aditya,

If you want to traverse between 2 activities like in your case, you should never finish Details activity. Instead without finishing Details activity, start SubDetails activity. If you want to come back, no coding required. If user presses BACK button, SubDetails Activity will be finished and DetailsActivity will come to foreground.

Finishing one activity and starting it again, is unnecessary overhead. Avoid it. Finish activity if it is absolutely necessary.

Also, there is no any way to restart finished activity.

Comment: Hello harry. Actually i want the app to quit once the user presses the back button when on SubDetailsActivity. Coz i want the DetailsActivity to show up when the user launches the app for thw first time. Thats the reason. I am creating a .properties file after pressing the button on DetailsActivity. Next time when the user launches the app, the app check for the file to be present. And if present, the SubDetailsActivity opens up. Else DetailsActivity remains.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Harry answered,

I want to add something for you. If you are programming for higher API Levels (e.g. Android API 13+) you can define a parent activity.

This way you don't need to make such complex implementations.

**For reference**

[Google Developers Guide to UP navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

[Stackoverflow ANSWER on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276027/how-can-i-return-to-a-parent-activity-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this!:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

I think it's very important how you declared the launchMode in your andriodManifest for your activities ! There should be the problem. Read carefully what is a task and how a back stack in android works.

Maybe you are finishing the task but at same time you are viewing the next activity which is in the same task ! After reopen it crashed because of this I think.  Hope it helps.