# parentActivityName forces onCreate

Tags: java, android

In my Android manifest, I am specifying a parentActivityName in order to utilise the back button displayed in the activity.

I find this however re-calls onCreate of the previous activity, in which I do several network calls and set up a recycler view widget.

This causes the screen to refresh entirely, I'd like to avoid this and deal with the recyclerview and what new content to display and delete to ensure the user flow is not jolted.

I currently set my application up in onCreate

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_container_list);

        final SwipeRefreshLayout swiperefreshContainerListRecyclerView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh_container_list_recyclerview);
    swiperefreshContainerListRecyclerView.setOnRefreshListener(
            new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    refreshContainerList();
                }
            }
    );

    // Get a handle on our RecyclerView for interactin and setup
    containerListRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.container_list_recyclerview);

    // Grab a new LayoutManager
    containerListLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    // Grab a new adapter
    List<ContainerModel> containers = new ArrayList<>();
    containerListRecyclerAdapter = new ContainerListRecyclerViewAdapter(containers, this);

    // Better performance as the size of our RecyclerView does not change
    containerListRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // Attach our LayoutManager to our RecyclerView
    containerListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(containerListLayoutManager);

    // Wire up adapter for RecyclerView
    containerListRecyclerView.setAdapter(containerListRecyclerAdapter);

    cAdvisorService = new CAdvisorService();

    cAdvisorService.fetchDataFromService(context, containerListRecyclerAdapter);

    System.out.println("Running onCreate!");
}
```

I already have logic within my cAdvisorService to deal with removing and adding items into the RecyclerView.

How do I deal with the fact that onCreate is called each time, forcing new instances of my RecyclerView and cAdvisorService?

Answer (score 1):

There way to achieve this by declaring your parent activity in your Android manifest as

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

, see more at: [How can I return to a parent activity correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276027/how-can-i-return-to-a-parent-activity-correctly)