# MainActivity restarts itself by back button in menu of another activity

Tags: android

I have MainActivity with mapFragment inside of it. And I have settings button that starts new activity with settings.The following code starts it

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == findViewById(R.id.btnSettings)){
        Intent AlarmPreferencesActivityIntent;
        AlarmPreferencesActivityIntent = new Intent(App.getContext(), AlarmPreferencesActivity.class);
        AlarmPreferencesActivityIntent.putExtra("alarm", alarm);
        App.getContext().startActivity(AlarmPreferencesActivityIntent);
    }
}
```

Manifest declaration of activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".Preferences.AlarmPreferencesActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm_preference"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.geoalarm.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

That settings activity has auto-generated back button in menu(you can see on screenshot).  [image]

So problem is when I press that button it doesn't return me back to MainActivity, but creates it again. Method onDestroy of MainActivity triggers when I press that back button in settings activity. Can I do something to get MainActivity by clicking back button that was created before I started activity with settings?

Comment: How are you starting the settings activity?

Comment: I have simple button, that starts settings activity by clicking on it.

Comment: I understand that, I meant the code where you actually start the new activity.

Comment: soes it extend settingsActivity

Comment: Android may destroy an activity any time it's not visible.  You should expect this and be able to deal with it.

Comment: added that code to description

Comment: Are you trying to say that the Google map displayed in your mapFragment is recreated? Or Are you sure MainActivity is recreated? Did MainActivity's OnCreate get called again?

Comment: yes I'm pretty much sure, OnCreate is called again.

Comment: Can you please post the code here. of the settings activity, its manifest declaration and how is the intent called from main activity @BlindDespair

Comment: Plz try after removing the Intent.Flag_activity_new_task,

Comment: @BlindDespair did you write any intent in the back button of the settings activity.

Comment: point is back button is created automatically, so I don't work with it in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recollected I had a similar issue in one of my applications,

I used this code in my settings activity which extends PreferenceActivity
        and implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @Override
    public Intent getParentActivityIntent() {
        return super.getParentActivityIntent().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    }
```

Please add this to your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setting"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/SettingsTheme">>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.package.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

on options selected simply i created an intent of the settings activity and used it.

This worked in my case. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line of code

AlarmPreferencesActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Maybe this will help.

Comment: no, it didn't help. point is when settings activity is up, the old mainactivity is not destroyed yet. method onDestroy of MainActivity triggers when I press that back button in settings activity

Comment: added to description

Comment: android:launchMode="singleTop"            add this to your activity in manifest and let me know is it work

Comment: You may need to check this post....   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276027/how-can-i-return-to-a-parent-activity-correctly