# Intent lost on BACK button even if I try startActivityForResult, saveInstanceState in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-intent, fragmentpageradapter, startactivityforresult

I have this navigation schema in my android application:

> PrimaryActivity (... ListView onClick - sending *<PrimaryUri>* via
>   intent...) >
>   MasterActivity (TabLayout, ViewPager,
>   FragmentPageAdapter) >
>   FragmentA / FragmentB (...ListView onClick -
>   sending *<PrimaryUri>* + *<DetailUri>* via intent...) > DetailActivity.

Now when I press BACK button in **DetailActivity**, MasterActivity gets destroyed and recreated again with new instances of Fragment A and B **and Intent data (*<PrimaryUri>*) is lost**.

I tried persisting *<PrimaryUri>* between Activies by this way:

- override onSaveInstanceState / onCreate(Bundle) in MasterActivity, **but Bundle was always null** even onSaveInstance saves the data
- start DetailActivity with getActivity().startActivityForResult(..., set resultIntent in DetailActivity and call setResult(OK, ResultCode > 0)
  and read values in MasterActivity.onActivityResult... **But
  onActivityResult was never called**
- start DetailActivity with startActivityForResult, ...dtto...FragmentB.onActivityResult... **But onActivityResult is never
  called**
- checked manifest for wrong attributes

Now I really appreciate help for question: How to persist *<PrimaryUri>* in my application? I prefer to use intents and solve this strange behaviour. Some forum discussed errors in FragmentPageAdapter etc... Maybe I will refactor it for use of SharedPreferences if it will be quick solution...

**EDIT:** Some additional info:

In DetailActivity:

```
@Override  
public void finish() {  
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();  
    resultIntent.setData((Uri) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(FragmentB.MY_URI));  
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);  
    super.finish();  
}
```

In MasterActivity I have:

```
@Override  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
}
```

In FragmentB I have:

```
public void onItemSelected(Uri contentUri) {      
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);     
    intent.putExtra(PRIMARY_URI, mUri);...     
    startActivityForResult(intent, FragmentB.BACKTAG);  
} 

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {   
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);    
    switch (requestCode) {  
        case (FragmentB.BACKTAG): {  
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  
                mUri = data.get...  
            }  
        }  
        break;  
    }    
}
```

The strange behavior looks like:

1. I press BACK button in DetailActivity >
2. MasterActivity.onDestroy get called (why there?).. =
3. WeakReference to FragmentB is null and new instance is created =
4. onActivityResult of MasterActivity or FragmentB is never called.

I think that reason is that onDestroy appears while waiting for onActivityResult. But why it is called and why the MasterActivity isn't fully recreated to catch onActivityResult callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was headache, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276027/how-can-i-return-to-a-parent-activity-correctly/15933890#15933890) I found the solution after 2 days of futile attempts. This has nothing to do with FragmentPageAdapter. I am lucky woman!

Answer (score 0):

You were calling startActivityForResult in the fragments yes?

For your onActivityResult in the fragment to be called you first have to handle onActivityResult in the activity. Call the super.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

You should then be able to handle it in your fragment's onActivityResult.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work to me. I will add some additional info into original post.