# Maintain state between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-toolbar

My app has two activities: `MasterActivity` and `DetailActivity`.
`MasterActivity` has two visualization modes: *list mode* and *map mode*. An action bar item toggles between them.

I'd like to mantain the selected visualization mode when user goes into `DetailActivity` and comes back. In the beginning I used `SharedPreferences` but then user would get back his previous visualization mode even after a device boot or a long inactivity time, and that's not what I mean.

Then I switched to `Bundle` and `onSaveInstanceState` but, when user clicks on back button of `DetailActivity`, `onCreate`'s `Bundle` is always empty so I can't restore the previous visualization mode and it always reverts to the list one.

App uses a `Toolbar` and `AndroidManifest.xml` is configured like that:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.MasterActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_master"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".ui.DetailActivity"
    android:parentActivityName=".ui.MasterActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="it.returntrue.revalue.ui.MasterActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: could you add the code of the method: public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) in your DetailActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why `onSaveInstanceState` doesn't work for you. Your code would be like:

```
class MasterActivity extends Activity {
    private int mode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            mode = savedInstanceState.getInt("mode");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(mode == 1) {
            //list mode
        } else {
            // map mode
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("mode", mode);
    }
}
```

Nevertheless, consider to use [Androjeta](http://jeta.brooth.org/guide/androjeta/retain.html) framework (maintained by me). It comes with a number of features including `@Retain` which you can use in your case:

```
class MasterActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Retain
    int mode;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(mode == 1) {
            //list mode
        } else {
            // map mode
        }
    }
}
```

Note that here `MasterActivity` extends from `BaseActivity` so you need to create that too. Please, follow the link for details.

Comment: My code is nearly identical to yours. The problem is `onCreate`'s `savedInstanceState` is always null.

Comment: I think this behavior because of `parent activity` feature. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276027/how-can-i-return-to-a-parent-activity-correctly) is the issue on stackoveflow

Answer (score 0):

I have two approaches. It's basically the same, but different on how you store the data

1. Use a `Singleton`
2. Keep your `sharedprefs` model as it is

On both occasions, delete the values on the `Activity's onDestroy` method.