# Activity B: Go back to Activity A on Actionbar calls A.onCreate(). The Back button does not

Tags: android, back-button

I have activity AActivity which calls Activity BActivity.
In the `AndroidManifest` I specify B as follows:

```
<activity android:name=".main.BActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".main.AActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".main.AActivity" />
    </activity>
```

If I'm in `Activity B` and click on the phone's Back-Button, then I go back to `Activity A` without calling `A.onCreate();` again - that's how I want it to be. But If I'm in `Activity B` and click the `ActionBar's Back button` on the top left, then I go back to `Activity A` again, but `A.onCreate();` is called. How can I use the backbutton of the top of the Activity to behave in the manner the phone's back button does, i.e. not calling StartingActivity.onCreate() ?

Btw: Activity A and B are extending from `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: are you calling `finish()` while starting the `BActivity` intent?

Comment: where is your listener for back button of actionbar. show your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `OnClick(View view)` function call `finish()`. 
[Related guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in manifest inside activity A. read this following link for more details [return parent activity correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276027/how-can-i-return-to-a-parent-activity-correctly/15933890#15933890)

Answer (score 0):

Call `finish()` `onBackPressed()` and `onOptionsItemSelected()` when `id == android.R.id.home`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    if(EcologDriverAIDApplication.DEBUG){

        Log.i(TAG, "onBackPressed");

    }
    finish();

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //Back button pressed
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use the backbutton of the top of the Activity to behave in the manner the phone's back button does, i.e. not calling StartingActivity.onCreate() ?

```
//declare android:onClick="backButtonPressed" in your xml in the back button layout
public void backButtonPressed(View view) {
    onBackPressed();
}
```

**Why it should work:**

When you press the bottom back button of android, `onBackPressed()` is called. As you have said, the bottom back button tap works the way you want it to. Therefore, just call it from your click listener of the back button at the action bar