# How to restore Activity with my current Listview Data while switching between activities?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

Hello Everyone,
               I had do a search on activity retain state.So I am getting to options/solutions for that:-

1. Using savedInstanceState() and retainInstanceState() methods.
2. Using Parent Child hierarchy declare in manifest and its working.
   **(Example Url:-[How can I return to a parent activity correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276027/how-can-i-return-to-a-parent-activity-correctly)But) I had same problem mention in Note scetion of the answer.That case is match with my problem.**

So,I want to retain the activity states just like Whats app(call/chats/contacts fragments).

- But In My scenario,I am fetching the contacts from server.So how can I persist my data while switching between chat and my fragment activity?
- So while timing to fetch new data of my contact list from server.I want to save ui of my listview/recyclerview with old data previously I had.

**Also suggest which method is good from above two methods or need to implement in other way.**

Comment: Cache the list in SQLite?

Comment: With Activities in Android having Lifecycles, I think a good option would be to 'decouple' you're Activities from your Data/Model.  Have you thought about using a Model/View/Presenter (MVP) structure? A small app I wrote using a MVP structure - code is quite heavily commented so should be easy to follow - https://github.com/TreeFrogApps/A3_WeatherService

Comment: @Mark Keen Have you any other example in which you are using MVP structure to keep searched weather data cached while I am switching between two activities.

Comment: @Anil The example uses a type of LRUCache that retains WeatherData, for a reasonable time until its considered 'stale'.  If you are navigating to another activity, then pressing back will pop the backstack and return you to the previous Activity.  The MVP structure I use keeps the associated Activities' Presenter in a retained headless fragment that uses setRetainInstance(true).  With this in mind you can persist the Presenter, and any data/lists etc. that are required by the UI.  So even if onCreate in the Activity is called it doesn't matter as you're retainedFragment holds the Presenter.