# Back button go to the previous screen used, even though i set "android:parentActivityName"

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, manifest

in my `Manifest.xml` file i'm setting the `android:parentActivityName` for all the activities i'm using, 
But despite i'm setting it to a certain screen, it goes to the last screen used anyway.

**is there a way of my controlling what screen will the back button go, without setting it in the `android:parentActivityName` ?**

Also why is it not working ?

This is my `AndroidManifes.xml` File>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="apps.radwin.wintouch">

    <!-- Permisions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <!-- Applicatino properties -->
    <application
        android:name=".appContext"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">

        <!-- META DATA -->
        <!-- Active android Meta -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
            android:value="Wintouchdatabase.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
            android:value="1" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_MODELS"
            android:value="apps.radwin.wintouch.models.ProjectsModel, apps.radwin.wintouch.models.WorkingOrdersModel, apps.radwin.wintouch.models.BandsModel" />

        <!-- dDfault Meta -->
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"
            android:required="false" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_W"
            android:value="632.0dip" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H"
            android:value="598.0dip" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Activities -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.alignmentActivities.Scanning_Barcode_Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.alignmentActivities.Project_Selection_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.alignmentActivities.Aligment_Scan_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_aligment__scan_"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.alignmentActivities.Scanning_Barcode_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.alignmentActivities.Fine_Aligment_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fine__aligment_"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.alignmentActivities.Aligment_Scan_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.alignmentActivities.Project_Selection_Activity"
            android:label="Wintouch"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.alignmentActivities.Add_New_Project_Activity"
            android:label="Add new Project"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.alignmentActivities.Project_Selection_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.alignmentActivities.WorkOrders_election_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_work_orders_election_"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activities.alignmentActivities.Project_Selection_Activity" />
        /activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.alignmentActivities.Splash_Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.alignmentActivities.Add_New_Work_Order"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add__new__work__order"
            android:parentActivityName=".activities.alignmentActivities.WorkOrders_election_Activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.alignmentActivities.Testings_Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_testings_"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.alignmentActivities.Workorder_Settings_Report"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_workorder__settings__report"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thnx

Comment: Have you tried implementing this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/15933890/5515371

Comment: yea, tried it with the android:launchMode="singleTop" flag it didn't work

Comment: override onBackPressed() and try