# Android: Activity onCreate savedInstanceState allways is null

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, onsaveinstancestate

So, I know is question is duplicated, but I didn't find solution in these answers.
I have a MainActivity and GameDetailActivity. MainActivity hierarchical parent of GameDetailActivity. Here it is declarations in manifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2"
        android:noHistory="false"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GameDetailActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme2"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:noHistory="false"
        >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="de.exam.example.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
```

here AppTheme2 declaration:

```
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

here back logic in GameDetailActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
                TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                        .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                        .startActivities();
            } else {
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
            }
            return true;
        default:break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and when I press home up (back "<-") button in GameDetailActivity I am getting always savedInstanceState is null in MainActivity. I don't understand why saved data lost in MainActivity.

**EDIT**

Here start GameDetailActivity code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), GameDetailActivity.class);
i.putExtra("game", clickedGame);
startActivity(i);
```

Anybody know how to fix this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Post the code where you start `GameDetailActivity`.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15933890/758104

Comment: @earthw0rmjim I added start code GameDetailActivity, look to edited area

Answer (score 1):

**Navigate up with a new back stack**

> When user presses the Up button after entering your activity from
>   another app's task, your app starts a `new task with` the appropriate
>   back stack before navigating up.

**Solution**

**Navigate Up to Parent Activity**

> When you call this method, it finishes the current activity and starts
>   `(or resumes)` the appropriate parent activity. If the target parent
>   activity is in the task's back stack, it is `brought forward.` The way
>   it is brought forward depends on whether the parent activity is able
>   to handle an onNewIntent() call.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp)

---

```
   @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the
>   current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that
>   activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and
>   this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a
>   new Intent.
>   May this will solve your problem

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()== android.R.id.home) {
        Intent intent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `savedInstanceState` bundle is getting saved in `onSaveInstanceState()`.

`onSaveInstanceState()` is called when the OS destroys the `Activity` (to reclaim resources for example, or because of a configuration change), it is not guaranteed to be called by simply navigating through activities.

Comment: Do you recommend use other variants such as SharedPreference, static fields in application class?

Comment: It's hard to suggest a solution without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve. `SharedPreferences` could be a possible solution to persist the data. If you would like to use the data in `GameDetailActivity` also, you could just pass it in the `Intent` as an extra.