# Android: using toolbar with homeAsUpButton does call onCreate instead of onResume

Tags: android

I use toolbar in activity like this:

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And this code in AppCombatActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}
```

In Manifest I defined parent activity.

It works. But everytime I press the button 'onCreate' is called on parent activity. But thats not what I want. Whenn I press the back-button on the device it goes back to previous activity and just calls onResume. That is what it also should do when I press the back button in the toolbar.

Any Ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: If the parent activity has not been created before or it is closed with `finish();` of course it will call `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file add

```
launchmode="singleTop"
```

in the parent activity's declaration.
Check out LorenzCK's answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15933890/5987223

Answer (score 0):

Add this for your requirement...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //Start activity which you want... to call onCreateMethod
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's not working for me. But point me in the right direction Solution was:   implement `onBackPressed();` at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            **onBackPressed();**
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```