# Navigating back to previous activity without an Up button

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I go back to the previous activity, if a certain condition is met or if a certain button is clicked? 
I am using `startActivity(intent)` to start this activity

Comment: Need more information Such as if you wish to pop activity from backstack

Comment: There's a difference between "parent activity" and "previous activity in backstack". Which one do you want to navigate to?

Answer (score 1):

This answer explains it properly,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15933890/6756421

Below is the answer from the above link answered by [palindrom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73573/palindrom),

You declared activity A with the standard launchMode in the Android manifest. According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode), that means the following:

> The system always creates a new instance of the activity in the target
>   task and routes the intent to it.

Therefore, the system is forced to recreate activity A (i.e. calling onCreate) even if the task stack is handled correctly.

To fix this problem you need to change the manifest, adding the following attribute to the A activity declaration:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

*Note*: calling finish() (as suggested as solution before) works only when you are completely sure that the activity B instance you are terminating lives on top of an instance of activity A. In more complex workflows (for instance, launching activity B from a notification) this might not be the case and you have to correctly launch activity A from B.

Answer (score 0):

Just use (if going to the main activity):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, homeActivity);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

whenever the condition is met or if something is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `finish()` in your activity to close it and return to the previous

Answer (score 0):

You can use `finish()` or `super.onBackPressed()`